# Intersection of spheres with elemental geometry

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I have a cube of side "a", and two spheres located diametrically opposite in the vertices of the cube, the radius of the spheres is "a", using elemental geometry to calculate the common region of intersection (volume) of both spheres inside the cube .

if a=1

\begin{array}{rr}(1)&x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\\(2)&(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2 = 1\\\\ \end{array}
I can not think of using elemental geometry

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yeah there is a way to calculate the volume using elementary geometry, as long as you take the formula for the volume of a spherical cap for granted. Do you still need this solution?

Answer (score 4):

---

[image: TwoSpheresInt]

---

The intersection of the sphere is a 3D "lens"
as depicted to the right (and barely discernable to the left).

Comment: How did you calculate the volume of that lentil

Comment: It really is a lentil, or a lens.

Comment: @Lubin: Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

You are wise to use $a=1$. With this, you know the distance $d$ between the diametrically opposite vertices. Why don’t you place these vertices now on the $z$-axis, to the points $(0,0,\pm d/2)$. Now you are just finding the volume between the unit spheres centered at these points, in other words twice the volume in the $\{z\ge0\}$-halfspace below the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z+d)^2=1$. I’m sure you know how to do that.

Comment: It would be like calculating (Area spherical sphere-cone area) * 2, or I'm wrong, I can not see it.

Comment: Well, with Prof. O’Rourke’s picture, you should be able to see it; with my description, you should be able to set up the integral.

Comment: Is without integrals, with elemental geometry

Comment: @susydiaz: The key phrase is [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap). Then you can follow Lubin's suggestion.